# Calculating age while inserting into a new table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of salespeople and I'm trying to create a second table from that data to establish the senior sales team.  In the first table we have their birthdates stored however I want to just store their current age in the new table.

This is my salesperson schema

```
CREATE TABLE Salesperson
(
SalespersonId BIGINT,
Name VARCHAR(50),
BirthDate DATE,
Salary INT
);
```

All I'm trying to do is add their name and age to the new table

```
INSERT INTO SeniorSales (Name, Age)
SELECT Name, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, @BirthDate, @TargetDate) / 365.25) 
FROM Salesperson 
WHERE Salary > 100,000;
```

I'm getting an error that says I have "Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'" I will admit that I'm relatively new to mySQL and I took the age calculation function off a google search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DATEDIFF sintax use two date only this way  DATEDIFF(date1,date2)

in your case you should use

```
 INSERT INTO SeniorSales (Name, Age)
 SELECT Name, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(@TargetDate, @BirthDate) / 365.25) 
 FROM Salesperson 
 WHERE Salary > 100,000;
```